# ASP.NET Core returns 404 instead of 500 when using ExceptionHandler PipeLine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GET Index");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("POST Index");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Both the GET and POST request returns a statuscode of 500. This is the expected behavior.

But when I add `app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/debug/error");`
In the Startup.cs file, the POST request does no longer return a statuscode of 500, instead it returns 404. The GET request is still working as it should by returning a statuscode of 500.

DebugController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DebugController : Controller
{


    [HttpGet("error")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return StatusCode(500,"Hello, World! From debug controller");
    }
}
```

Any idé why adding `app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/debug/error");` would make the POST request behave this way?

A repo to reproduce this behavior can be found [Here](https://github.com/Zexuz/HttpPostExceptionTest).

Comment: You have a Get error, but no Post error action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using [`ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) with an ExceptionHandlingPath, as in your example, the main outcome is that the request path gets rewritten to instead use your new path (`/api/debug/error` in your case). You can see how this works in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L59):

```
if (_options.ExceptionHandlingPath.HasValue)
{
    context.Request.Path = _options.ExceptionHandlingPath;
}
```

If you continue to browse through the source, you'll see that the [`StatusCode` gets set to `500`](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L71), but the original request is left mostly intact.

In practical terms, this means you are being sent to a POST action on your `DebugController`, but you have only provided a GET action.

A simple way to fix this would be to make your `Index` action support both `GET` and `POST`, like so:

```
[HttpGet("error")]
[HttpPost("error")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return StatusCode(500,"Hello, World! From debug controller");
}
```

If you want to do something *different* for POST errors, you can just create a new action, decorated with `[HttpPost("error")]`.

---

Update: Some of this explanation now exists in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#exception-handler-page):

> The exception handling middleware re-executes the request using the *original* HTTP method. If an error handler endpoint is restricted to a specific set of HTTP methods, it runs only for those HTTP methods. For example, an MVC controller action that uses the `[HttpGet]` attribute runs only for GET requests. To ensure that all requests reach the custom error handling page, don't restrict them to a specific set of HTTP methods.
>
> To handle exceptions differently based on the original HTTP method:
>
> - For Razor Pages, create multiple handler methods. For example, use `OnGet` to handle GET exceptions and use `OnPost` to handle POST exceptions.
> - For MVC, apply HTTP verb attributes to multiple actions. For example, use `[HttpGet]` to handle GET exceptions and use `[HttpPost]` to handle POST exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been having a similar problem. I made an API controller callable from JavaScript. Everything works fine on development. I have noticed for a while that the API on the live site often returns a 404 error, even though the route is obviously there.

I think I have tracked down the issue which was 500 errors caused by subtle differences on the live site, most notably using a different version of the SQL database on live and dev. So basically my API's GET method was returning a 404 when it should have been returning 500. It sounds as if the solution is to ensure my API methods have both [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes.

One other issue I have noticed is that API calls are sometimes cached if you use:

```
app.UseResponseCaching();
```

in Startup.cs. This very much depends on your hosting environment. I append a random number to my API route that resolves this.